# How to specify the all the subclasses of a base class in aspectJ?

Tags: aop, aspectj

```
// we would like to narrow this to subclasses ...
boolean around(Object other): 
  execution(public boolean com.basistech.rosette.dm.*.equals(java.lang.Object)) {
}
```

I'd like to narrow this further to only subclasses of a specified base class instead of all the classes in the package. How?

Answer (score 2):

You want this pointcut syntax:

```java
execution(public boolean com.basistech.rosette.dm.MyBaseClass+.equals(java.lang.Object))
```

Please note the `+` character after the class name. It will affect `MyBaseClass` and all of its subclasses, no matter in which package the subclasses are defined.